# Custom support.v7.widget.Toolbar not showing on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

If I understand correctly, the purpose of this widget is to make toolbar compatible with older versions of android (like 4.x), but for some reason when I run my app on actual device with android 4.x I'm not seeing my toolbar. And in emulator with Android 6 everything is ok.

I'm using **@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** in my theme and my activity extends **AppCompatActivity**.

This is how my toolbar looks like:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/my_toolbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
  android:elevation="4dp"
  android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">
```

Included in my activity xml:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_main"></include>
```

And added in activity code on create:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

Any hint why this not showing on android 4.x?

Comment: kindly check the default style/theme of the activity that you are using if the parent is AppCompat like this <style name="MyCustomStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

Comment: Can you be more specific? I'm not sure that I understand what do you mean by that. In my theme style I don't have any style customization if that's what you mean.

Comment: on you manifest try to put something like this even you dont have a custom theme style.. android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"

Comment: Same thing, but I was playing around little bit by wrapping my toolbar with android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout and the only situation when toolbar is displayed is when I wrapped my  webview control which is under toolbar, but that's weird...

Comment: OMG, how stupid I was! :-/ It looks like I'm getting older, and sleepy at 10PM already! :) I forget to wrap my content bellow into relative layout and because of that my layout was messed up on older version and toolbar looks hidden but he was actually there. :-/ Thanks for help anyway.

Comment: anyway, i can relate to you! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please Try This.

Change your XML Layout as.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: What's the important thing in it??

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting a non-existing toolbar id. Put:

```
toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
```

instead.

Comment: I'm including this as <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/actionbar_main"
        ></include> so toolbar is  exist, it's not null, and as I said it works on emulator.

Comment: try it and let me know of the results.

Comment: I'm getting exception when I use your piece of code, as I said, toolbar exist with the code above.

Comment: Are you using an AppBarLayout ?

Comment: No, I don't have that. I have RelativeLayout and directly inside of that I have this include piece to add tool bar xml from above.

Comment: I'm not sure... did you find the solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94326/discussion-between-shp-and-developerx).